# Coverflow : How to specifying the widget in an XML and how to do infinite loop?

Tags: android, xml, loops, gallery, coverflow

Coverflow is gallery widget. 
Based on this url > http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html
I implement coverflow for my project as a main menu UI and I'm having issues.
The problem is I really have no idea how to specifying the CoverFlow in an XML. Because I want to add images and textview on that activity.
Does anyone have any idea?
All the works is done on code, while I want it separated to XML as usual.

And also, does anyone have any idea how to do infinite loop on coverflow ?

Thank you

Comment: What do u mean by infinite loop?

Comment: what i mean by infinite loop is, for example : if coverflow has 5 item, then when the app start, the centre of screen would show the item #3. when I swipe to right, i will find the last item is on the right and cannot swipe to the right anymore because no more item is provided. what i want is it able to loop back to item #1 and so on..

Answer (score 2):

That's really simple. In your XML file provide the widget like this,

```
<com.example.coverflow.CoverFlow
    android:id="@+id/coverflow"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Note that **com.example.coverFlow** refers to the Package Name of your project and **CoverFlow** refers to the Custom Class used for Coverflow.

Now in your onCreate() you could have initialized your CoverFlow something like this,

```
CoverFlow coverFlow = new CoverFlow(this);
```

Instead of this, replace it with the below line,

```
CoverFlow  coverFlow =  (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed instruction. I will try it asap and will post it here if its work. :)

Comment: Hi Andro, the instruction you said does not work. The app go Forced Close instead of running as usual. The error log in LogCat i found is : 04-18 07:46:34.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1847):  at id.co.ajsmsig.display.CoverFlowMain.onCreate(CoverFlowMain.java:76). And the line 75 & 76 is : coverFlow =  (CoverFlowClass) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);
   
   coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

Comment: This might be "really simple", as mentioned, but I'm also having issues with this. I'm trying to figure out in original example, and when switched to use XML I constantly get "Inflate Exception - Binary XML file line" ...I did as you suggested here, removed "new Coverflow" and initialized the one on mine layout but it does not work...

Comment: Check for the package name of the Coverflow class. You might be providing wrong package name. Or edit your question and add the xml and other class with package names